# Generally disable dimension dropping for matrices?

Tags: r, matrix

As we all know, R tries to reduce matrices to vectors if its column- or row-dimension is 1. This automatic dropping of dimensions can be prevented by use of the `drop=F` command.

However, I am currently writing a large R package and would require to disable dimension dropping on several hundred occasions in my code, so that I would have to manually find these locations and add `drop=F`  many hundred times.

Therefore, I would like to know if there's any option or possibility to **generally** disable dimension dropping for matrices in R?

Comment: I also thought of the Defaults package, but it seems to give a parse error if you specify `[` for the `.name` argument.

Comment: the default dimension dropping is seriously brain-damaged. Especially in case of multidimensional arrays (dim >= 3) it's totally unexpected.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do it by redefining the `[` function:

```
x <- matrix(1:4,2)

`[` <- function(...) base::`[`(...,drop=FALSE)
x[,1]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

You cannot override the `drop` argument when you call it now though, so you might want to use it sparingly and delete when done.

Comment: This'll allow you to set drop=TRUE when you want to: ``[` <- function(..., drop=FALSE) base::`[`(...,drop=drop)` . (b/c of the backticks, Markdown won't render this properly in a comment, but the idea should be clear.)

Comment: Doesn't this interfere with the ``[`` functions defined for classes other than `matrix`?

Comment: It is probably advisable to not export the overwritten `[` function in the package to avoid messing up codes for the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, especially James and Josh. This is what I had been looking for. It's often quite difficult to find the correct syntax for accessing primitive R-internals. ;)