# Subsetting R array: dimension lost when its length is 1

Tags: r, subset

When subsetting arrays, R behaves differently depending on whether one of the dimensions is of length 1 or not.  If a dimension has length 1, that dimension is lost during subsetting:

```
ax <- array(1:24, c(2,3,4))
ay <- array(1:12, c(1,3,4))
dim(ax)
#[1] 2 3 4
dim(ay)
#[1] 1 3 4
dim(ax[,1:2,])
#[1] 2 2 4
dim(ay[,1:2,])
#[1] 2 4
```

From my point of view, ax and ay are the same, and performing the same subset operation on them should return an array with the same dimensions.  I can see that the way that R is handling the two cases might be useful, but it's undesirable in the code that I'm writing.  It means that when I pass a subsetted array to another function, the function will get an array that's missing a dimension, if I happened to reduce a dimension to length 1 at an earlier stage.  (So in this case R's flexibility is making my code less flexible!)

How can I prevent R from losing a dimension of length 1 during subsetting?  Is there another way of indexing?  Some flag to set?

Comment: not identical but maybe of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196724/generally-disable-dimension-dropping-for-matrices

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you've found out by default R drops unnecessary dimensions.  Adding `drop=FALSE` while indexing can prevent this:

```
> dim(ay[,1:2,])
[1] 2 4
> dim(ax[,1:2,])
[1] 2 2 4
> dim(ay[,1:2,,drop = F])
[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you, Dason.  Perfect.  I wouldn't have guessed that you could do it that way. (I knew it was a FAQ, but it's hard to construct a useful search string for an answer.)

Comment: Follow up question: How can I get this syntax information from the built-in help system?

Comment: R has a nasty habit of side-effects in its default behaviour :(