# Prevent R from dropping names when extracting elements from a named list

Tags: r

When extracting elements from a named list, R automatically drops the names when the list is of length 1. Is it possible to keep the names?

Exemple:

Code:R

```
lin_mod = lm(data, CompStength~ .)
anova(lin_model)
```

`anova(lin_model)[,"Sum Sq"]` does not keep the names (e.g. CA.TA, TA.C, ...) but returns

```
     [1]   86.103991 2331.962769  932.229151 1415.558985  457.608362
```

I would like to get:

```
                 Sum Sq 
CA.TA             86.1   
TA.C            2332.0  
W.C              932.2
```

Just as when I run `anova(lin_model)[,c("Sum Sq","Df")]` I get:

```
               Sum Sq   Df
CA.TA             86.1  3
TA.C            2332.0  3
W.C              932.2  2
Temp            1415.6  2
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a `drop = FALSE` duplicate or canonical question now...it's also listed in most official R FAQs.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12755397/324364) is a possibility, but there may be better ones...

Comment: `anova(lin_model)[, "Sum Sq", drop = FALSE]`?

Comment: Also covered in the SO R-Docs in the "basic subsetting/data frame" section: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1686/basic-subsetting/5447/data-frames#t=201702082311161733888