# How to slice a matrix in R and keep the resulting column vector as an actual column vector indeed?

Tags: r, matrix, slice

The problem that I'm having can be illustrated using the following matrix:

```
b <- cbind(matrix(c(1, 0, 0), nrow = 3), 
           matrix(c(0, 0, 0), nrow = 3), 
           matrix(c(2, 0, 1), nrow = 3))

b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    2
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1
```

Sometimes I need to slice matrices like the above, but when the slice keeps just one column or just one row the resulting slice then ceases to be a matrix. For instance, when I slice matrix *b* above and keep the last column and all rows as in the operation

```
b[seq(3), c(3)]
```

I get

```
# [1] 2 0 1
```

However, I would like to have the following result:

```
#      [,1]
# [1,]    2
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    1
```

What is a simple way to obtain the above result? Is there a slicing method that returns the result as above?

Comment: `b[i, j, drop = FALSE]`.  See also `?Extract`.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755397)?

Comment: Yeah, @MikaelJagan. That question would have worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b[seq(3), c(3), drop = FALSE]
```

Which can be simplified in this case to:

```
b[,3,drop = FALSE]
```