# Error in df[ , "x", drop= FALSE] <- rnorm(10) disappears when setting drop= FALSE as default - why?

Tags: r, matrix, default

I dislike that dataframes become a vector while selecting only one column. See here:

```
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(10))
df[ , "x"] # Not a dataframe anymore!
```

Therefore I started to use `drop= FALSE`. Like this:

```
df[ , "x", drop= FALSE] # Still a dataframe!
```

This has become a habit and I started to use it when replacing values but this gives an error (`unused argument (drop = FALSE)`). See here:

```
df[ , "x"] <- rnorm(10) # All good
df[ , "x", drop= FALSE] <- rnorm(10) # error!
```

Interestingly, I do not get this error if I [set `drop= FALSE` argument as defeault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196724/generally-disable-dimension-dropping-for-matrices). See here:

```
`[` <- function(...) base::`[`(...,drop=FALSE)
df[ , "x"] <- rnorm(10) # No error!
```

Why is there a difference? Shouldn't `df[ , "x", drop= FALSE] <- rnorm(10)` result in same behavior as `df[ , "x"] <- rnorm(10)` after setting `drop= FALSE` as default?

Comment: `[` and `[<-` are two different primitives, overriding the former does not affect the latter.